# How to add a header in the margin?

Tags: html, printing, header, report

I need to include a header in a page like this simple Google page:

[image: Example of a header]

I am trying to put the text "Google" inside the top margin of the page but it's 2.5 cm under, when the top margin ends). I want this:

[image: My page with bad header]

My HTML file:

```
<html lang="es-AR">
<body>
    <header>Google</header>
    <h1 class="title">Hello, world</h1>
    Trying to put a header.
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS file:

```
@page {
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    margin-top: 2.5cm;
    margin-right: 2.5cm;
    margin-bottom: 2.5cm;
    margin-left: 2.5cm;
}
```

The page is a report so it will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to take the margin-top from the `@page` (since you will not have an actual margin on page view, you want an html content to be there) and give the header fixed `height` of 2.5cm which will function as your top margin:

```
@page{
      size: 21cm 29.7cm;
      margin-right: 2.5cm;
      margin-bottom: 2.5cm;
      margin-left: 2.5cm;
}

header{
    height: 2.5cm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way:

```
@page {
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    margin-top: 0.5cm;
    margin-right: 2.5cm;
    margin-bottom: 2.5cm;
    margin-left: 2.5cm;
}

header {
    height: 2cm;
}
```